# Pivot Table sorting by Second-Component of Time Column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I use pivot tables all the time, I've never seen this before.

I create a pivot table based on this time column from a database query:

[image]

The pivot table fields show this Discharge Time column, as expected.

[image]

When I check it, three more fields appear. I uncheck them all because I want to simply sort by the time, I don't want to further segregate into days/hours/minutes.

[image]

Now I'm in an odd situation where my data is being sorted/grouped based on the second-component of the time? Here is what my pivot table currently looks like:

[image]

This is worthless to sort the data like this. How can I overcome this? Why is the pivot table not allowing me to segregate by second-component? I've used pivot tables many other times with this same type of setup (similar queries to database also), and I've never had any situations where it is sorting by the second-component of the time.

I suppose I can alter the database query to remove the second-component of the time, but I don't really want to do this. Besides it doesn't make sense because I have other spreadsheets that return times with a second-component, and the pivot table does not have this issue. Also I'm not even confident that this would fix the problem, since this would effectively just set all of the second-components to `00`, not actually remove it.

---

P.S. Here is how my data is formatted, doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can highlight the field, go to the Pivot Table - Group Setting under Analyze on the top menu. Click on "Ungroup", or unselect "Seconds" in Group Selection.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Such a simple setting, had no idea where to find it. I have no idea why the default setting apparently changed, because I never had to deal with this until today. Thanks again.